# How to get generic type from generic definition and generic arguments?

Tags: c#, reflection

In C#, how can I construct generic type from generic definition and generic arguments like

```
var genericDefinition = typeof(List);
var genericArgument = typeof(string);
// How can I get the Type instance representing List<string> from the 2 variables above?
```

In my usecase, the generic argument is dynamically resolved. Is this possible in C#? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as `typeof(List)`. However, `typeof(List<>)` works fine, and is the open generic type. Then you just use:

```
var genericDefinition = typeof(List<>);
var genericArgument = typeof(string);
var concreteListType = genericDefinition.MakeGenericType(new[] {genericArgument});
```

and you should find that `concreteListType` is `typeof(List<string>)`.