# Pass type of class as generic type from string dynamically

Tags: c#

If I have number of classes like class A, class B, class C and so on.

and I want to pass this as a generic type to list based on value of string variable like if string is "A", then pass class A, if it is "B" then class B and so on (no conditional check as value of string is not decided).

So if there is a string variable with value of "A", then type of that class should be passed as following.

```
IEnumerable<A> obj = SomeClassObj.GetData<A>(); //Here, need to add type of class A
```

So what is the way to achieve this?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: I updated question. is that fine now?

Comment: "So if I select string A", where did the string suddenly come from, everything else you describe is already solved by `List<A>`.

Comment: What about: `switch (s) { case "A": return new List<A>(); case "B": return new List<B>(); }` ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. Number of string is not limited. So it will be great if something dynamic solution.

Comment: Should be able to construct them with reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432314/how-to-get-generic-type-from-generic-definition-and-generic-arguments

Comment: Ok, then what about: `IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("Full typename here")))` ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. What will be that if it is of IEnumerable<A>?

Comment: You can't construct an object of an interface, you have to construct it of a type that implements the interface. And you can't declare the variable as something generic.

Comment: sorry. value will be assigned like this from => SomeClassObj.GetData<A>()

Comment: @mjwills. Because otherwise I'll have to write a big switch case. :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to make use of reflection to do stuff like that , try below code

```
    object obj = 
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("A");
      var listType = typeof(List<>);
      var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(obj.GetType());
      var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
```

or you can do make use of generic do as below

```
public class Utility
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CreateDynamicList<T>()
    {
        Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
        var listType = typeof(List<>);
        var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeParameterType);
        return (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(constructedListType, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

use it like

```
               object obj =
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("A");

        Type utility = typeof(Utility);
        var mi = utility.GetMethod("CreateDynamicList", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var m = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { obj.GetType() });
        IEnumerable<A> obj=  m.Invoke(this, new object[] { obj }) as  IEnumerable<A>;
        //here you need to convert it to given type 
        // or you can do this 
        dynamic list = m.Invoke(this, new object[] { obj });
        list.Add(new A();
```

what every way you go at the end you have to type cast return value to given type.

Comment: what if that is IEnumerable<A>?

Comment: Here A is not fixed. we need it as class type from string.

Comment: Here also A is fixed. So cant implement that way.

Comment: @HardikViradiya -`object obj =
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("A");` this is dynamic ...at the end you have to decide type ...C# doent work a way if you want full string base

Comment: okk. I guess I got my answer then, it is not possible what I want. :)

Comment: @HardikViradiya - yes cannot do much if you want to just go with string value , at some point you have to come up with actual type..as C# is Static type language ...however you can check dynamic types in C# that provide somewaht dynamic